# Show full plan in Pytest

Tags: python, plugins, pytest

I'm looking for a way in Pytest to show the full test and fixture plan instead of just listing the test cases via `--collect-only`.

This is the best I can get now:

```
TestClass1
  TestCase1
  TestCase2
TestClass2
  TestCase3
  TestCase4
```

This is what I'm looking for (should match the execution order):

```
Fixture1_Setup_ModuleScope
  Fixture2_Setup_ClassScope
    TestClass1
      Fixture3_Setup_FunctionScope
        TestCase1
      Fixture3_Teardown_FunctionScope
      TestCase2
  Fixture2_Teardown_ClassScope
  TestClass2
    TestCase3
    TestCase4
Fixture1_Teardown_ModuleScope
```

I looked around for such Pytest plugin and none seems to provide this. Not even as parsing of the result, let alone something that could be generated without running the tests. I understand that it's not *needed* for Pytest testing, but it's something I've learned to like in one of our older internal test frameworks, if only for validating my intention with reality.

Am I missing some obvious solution here? How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `pytest --setup-plan`.

> show what fixtures and tests would be executed but don't execute anything.

```sh
pytest --setup-plan
# ...                                                                                                                                        
# assert_test.py 
#         assert_test.py::TestTest::test_test
# click_test.py 
#         click_test.py::test_echo_token
# fixture_test.py 
#         SETUP    F env['dev']
#         SETUP    F folder['dev_data']
#         fixture_test.py::test_are_folders_exist[dev-dev_data] (fixtures used: env, folder)
#         TEARDOWN F folder['dev_data']
#         TEARDOWN F env['dev']
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for but couldn't find. Thanks!